# Removing VB Compiler from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC Application Web.Config file, I could find two compilers under system.codedom.
All my application code is written using C# only, and I don't need VB Compiler. 
Can I remove the entry for VB compiler. Will it affect the application performance if I don't remove it?

```
 <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @mjwills Nothing.. Rebuild succeeded.

Comment: Well that answers `Can I remove the entry for VB compiler.` then.

Comment: There is a very slight performance cost when new code is added/updated. IIS doesn't have to load that compiler when checking the new/updated files before starting the application